# eval (@atlas_pagename)

Tags: qgis, 3d

In QGIS 3.6, I'm successfully using the "eval (@atlas_pagename)" option that automates the generation of class maps when data
are organized by different fields and making use of the Atlas of the composer option.
However, when trying to use it in the 3D environment the command, it was not recognized.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what do u call "class maps" ?

Comment: Map class is categorized symbology or rule-based symbology, where I need to generate symbology sorted by month (60 classes) these classes are in different fields in the table, that is, I have 60 fields. In the layoute using Atlas works very well, but I also need to include in the layoute the 3D images.